# Can a task be created in Camunda Workflow outside of a process?

Tags: task, camunda

We had built a custom workflow in our project and we are looking to migrate to a BPMN 2.0 standard workflow management tool. While doing our analysis, we chose Camunda as the preferred tool (Community Edition). However, we need to continue to support a feature to create an adhoc task. (task created outside of a workflow process)

Can anyone respond if that's possible? If yes, what are the downsides or things to lookout for if the approach is chosen.

Comment: What are the properties of the task? Or is it just to be documented?

Comment: It will be a user task. Assigned to the user in an adhoc manner and hence the adhoc task. It need not be tied to a specific workflow per say.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a task without connection to a process via API (see https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.6/org/camunda/bpm/engine/TaskService.html#newTask() for Java API). You do not have any "Task Definition" in that case, so you have to provide all necessary properties (name, assignee, priority, duedate, ...) yourself. Afterwards it follows the normal task lifecycle though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. We initially opted for this but this requires us to build too many customization around the generic task. Would you know if this is in anyway better than the creating a one-task process?

Comment: Define "Better". It has les overhead as you do not have any process involved. But on the other hand it is limited in terms on configuration and monitoring options.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a generic process like this:
[image: Adhock task]

**Set task description and assigne**
Here, the creater can set any task description for the worker and assign the task.

**Processing task**
The worker execute the task description and finish the task.

For creating the forms you can use embedded task form https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/user-guide/task-forms/#embedded-task-forms

Comment: Hi @Jklee.. Thanks for your reply. We are also building a one-task process which is generic in nature.. However, we have around 15,000 adhoc tasks created in our system with a custom workflow. If we migrate to Camunda one-task process, having 1000s of process will have any implications in terms of performance? I know that running processes are in *RU* tables vs completed processes are moved to *HI* tables..

Comment: The numbers you mention are no problem in Camunda. The only potential bottleneck you might face are complex queries, e.g. task qeuries involving a couple of process variables (which involves a couple of joins on the database). This can be easily checked/should be verified by a quick performance test.